# AngularJS ToDo List App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some problem when creating my todo list app using Angular JS. My HTML and Javascript code are the following :

HTML Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <style>
    .done-true {
      text-decoration: line-through;
      color: grey;
    }

    input:required {
    box-shadow:none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Todo</h2>

<div ng-controller="TodoListController">

<form ng-submit="addTodo()" name="form">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here" required>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add"> 
</form>

<div>Incompleted : {{remaining()}}</div>
<div>Completed : {{todos.length - remaining()}}</div>

<a href="" ng-click="delete()">Delete</a>

<ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy : $index:true">
       <button type="button" ng-click="remove()">&#10008;</button>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
       <span class="done-{{todo.done}}" ng-hide="editing">{{todo.text}}</span>
       <input type="text" ng-show="editing" ng-model="todo.text">
       <button type="submit" ng-hide="editing" ng-click="change(todo); editing === true">Edit</button>
       <button type="submit" ng-show="editing" ng-click="save(); editing === false">Save</button>
       <button type="submit" ng-show="editing" ng-click="cancel(); editing === false">Cancel</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<pre>NewField : {{newField | json}}</pre>
<pre>Todos : {{todos | json}}</pre>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript Code :

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', [])

app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.newField = {};

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };

    $scope.remaining = function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
          return count;
        };

    $scope.delete = function() {
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
           if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(){
        $scope.todos.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };

    $scope.editing = false;

    $scope.change = function(field){
        $scope.editing = $scope.todos.indexOf(field);
        $scope.newField = angular.copy(field);
    }

    $scope.save = function(index) {
        $scope.todos[$scope.editing] = $scope.todos;
        $scope.editing = false;      
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(index) {
        $scope.todos[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
        $scope.editing = false;      
    };



}]);
```

Here are my problem : 
1. My Todo list was still empty. When I added a list and clicked edit, it didn't show the edit form, save, and cancel button (It only copy to NewField). However, when I added a second list and clicked edit, it showed the edit form, save, and cancel button on the 2 list (not only the second list). Why ? What's wrong with my code ?

2. My save button is not working. When I changed the list in the edit form and clicked save. The list was emptied and placed on the bottom of other list. Why ?

Thanks
Billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `$scope.editing` toggling.
After updating one line of your code everything starts working well.
Updated `$scope.editing = $scope.todos.indexOf(field)` to `$scope.editing = true` within `$scope.change` function;

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', [])

app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.newField = [];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false, editing: false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };

    $scope.remaining = function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
          return count;
        };

    $scope.delete = function() {
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
           if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(){
        $scope.todos.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };


    $scope.change = function(field){
        var todoIndex = $scope.todos.indexOf(field);
        $scope.newField[todoIndex] = angular.copy(field);
        $scope.todos[todoIndex].editing = true;
    }

    $scope.save = function(index) {
      $scope.todos[index].editing = false;
      
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(index) {
        $scope.todos[index] = $scope.newField[index];      
    };



}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .done-true {
      text-decoration: line-through;
      color: grey;
    }

    input:required {
    box-shadow:none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Todo</h2>

<div ng-controller="TodoListController">

<form ng-submit="addTodo()" name="form">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here" required>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add"> 
</form>

<div>Incompleted : {{remaining()}}</div>
<div>Completed : {{todos.length - remaining()}}</div>

<a href="" ng-click="delete()">Delete</a>

<ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy : $index:true">
       <button type="button" ng-click="remove()">&#10008;</button>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
       <span class="done-{{todo.done}}" ng-hide="todo.editing">{{todo.text}}</span>
       <input type="text" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-model="todo.text">
       <button type="submit" ng-hide="todo.editing" ng-click="change(todo); todo.editing === true">Edit</button>
       <button type="submit" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-click="save($index); todo.editing === false">Save</button>
       <button type="submit" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-click="cancel($index); todo.editing === false">Cancel</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<pre>NewField : {{newField | json}}</pre>
<pre>Todos : {{todos | json}}</pre>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, it works for my first problem. Now, when I clicked edit on a list, all my list are in edit form instead of only one list that is selected in edit form.

And my save and cancel button works equally. Cancel saves the changes

Comment: I change the cancel function to 
`$scope.cancel = function(index) {
        $scope.todos.text = $scope.newField.text;
        $scope.editing = false;      
    };`
but still doesn't work

Comment: I have updated code snippet to interact with each todo separately in that  case you would get desired behaviour.

Comment: Hello, I have a new problem. Let's say I have 2 items. When I pressed edit on the first item and second item together (so both are in edit form), I press cancel on the first item but the effect is on the second item (mean the second item is cancelled by the cancel button of the first item). Why ?

Comment: @Billy checkout again i updated code snipped to fix described bug. Checkout how it works know...

Comment: Okay, I see there are still a bug. I see the the two is exchanging. You can try it first :) I can't tell it in words

Comment: Maybe, to make it easy, for example 2 items. When the first item is in edit form and I click edit on the second item, the first item isn't in edit form again (automatically close) and the second item is remain in edit form

Comment: @Billy please check again

Comment: Thank You, but I need your help once again. Beside the item, it has the delete button, but why I want delete the first item, the second item is deleted. I have reversed the item through HTML, but the array is not reversed. I see the problem is at `<pre>Todos : {{todos | json}}</pre>`. I input b, a but in the array is a, b

Comment: Okay I have done it. I changed push() to unshift(). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Okay, maybe do you have time ? My app is finished but left the LocalStorage

Comment: Hello, I want to let you know. If people add a new item while other item in edit form, by the way the other item is cancelled, the array will be changed